# Join returns NULL when data that matches is in the table

Tags: mysql, sql, join, mariadb

I'm trying to get results when both tables have the same machine number and there are entries that have the same number in both tables.
Here is what I've tried:

```
SELECT fehler.*,
  'maschine.Maschinen-Typ',
  maschine.Auftragsnummer,
  maschine.Kunde,
  maschine.Liefertermin_Soll 
FROM fehler 
JOIN maschine 
  ON ltrim(rtrim('maschine.Maschinen-Nr')) = ltrim(rtrim(fehler.Maschinen_Nr))
```

The field I'm joining on is a `varchar` in both cases. I tried without trims but still returns empty
I'm using MariaDB (if that's important).

Comment: Oh and i also tried inner join because thats essentially what im trying to do. only get results when the mashine number is in both tables

Comment: Are both columns the same case (upper/lower)?

Comment: Add some sample table data, the current result and the wanted result. All as formatted text, not images.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: @JohnHC yes its either just numbers or numbers with a '-' so for example: 603090 or 603090-001

Comment: @jarlh im using phpmyadmin if thats what you are asking (sorry im new to this)

Comment: @Jens why did you put `'maschine.Maschinen-Nr'` as a string, shouldn't it be without the apostrophes?

Comment: @Jens phpMyAdmin is just a GUI application (one of several) which can be used to connect to a database engine. However since you mentioned that particular tool, it only connects to MySQL databases, so the correct answer to jarlh's question is "MySQL". The database engine and the tools used to administer it are separate things.

Comment: @GoranKutlaca i was using the ' to mask it since when i didnt it always showed "unknown table field maschine.Maschinen" so it was missing the -Nr. i guess it dowsnt like the - whats the propper way to do it in that case?

Comment: Please read & act on [mcve].

Comment: When it said "unknown table field maschine.Maschinen" did you check whether table maschine had a field Maschinen? This is why a [mcve] is required for code questions. Read about identifiers & valid characters & back ticks & double quotes. You have commented that you suspect `-` is a problem, you should be reading the manual & researching before asking us more questions.

Comment: @philipxy the table maschine does not have the field Maschinen. It has the field Maschinen-Typ, the one im trying to use in the query. I get where you are coming from and ill try my best to update my question so it is reproducable

Comment: @Jens you should put `your_table_name.your_column_name`. Without being able to really see the names of your table columns, I would guess it to be `maschine.maschinen_typ` and `maschine.maschinen_nr` (with an underscore).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The single quotes are string delimiters. You are comparing `fehler.Maschinen_Nr` with the string `'maschine.Maschinen-Nr'`. In standard SQL you would use double quotes for names (and I think MariaDB allows this, too, certain settings provided). In MariaDB the commonly used name qualifier is the backtick:

```
SELECT fehler.*,
  `maschine.Maschinen-Typ`,
  maschine.Auftragsnummer,
  maschine.Kunde,
  maschine.Liefertermin_Soll 
FROM fehler 
JOIN maschine 
  ON trim(`maschine.Maschinen-Nr`) = trim(fehler.Maschinen_Nr)
```

(It would be better of course not to use names with a minus sign or other characters that force you to use name delimiters in the first place.)

As you see, you can use `TRIM` instead of `LTRIM` and `RTRIM`. It would be better, though, not to allow space at the beginning or end when inserting data. Then you wouldn't have to remove them in every query.

Moreover, it seems `Maschinen_Nr` should be primary key for the table `maschine` and naturally a foreign key then in table `fehler`. That would make sure `fehler` doesn't contain any `Maschinen_Nr` that not exists exactly so in `maschine`.

Comment: Ok i tried that but i get the error unknow tablefield 'maschine.Maschinen-Typ' in field list. but when i look at the structure of my table maschine i see the field : `5  Maschinen-Typ  varchar(255)  latin1_swedish_ci   Ja  NULL `

Comment: That is strange. Can you change the table? Then make this `maschinen_typ` (and `maschinen_nr`) to play it safe.

Comment: I did exactly that. changes the minuses to underscores and now the join works. thanks alot. i guess i have more reading to do before i do more stupid mistakes like that. thanks!

Answer (score 3):

ON ltrim(rtrim('maschine.Maschinen-Nr')) = ltrim(rtrim(fehler.Maschinen_Nr)) seems wrong...

Is fehler.Maschinen_Nr really the string 'maschine.Maschinen-Nr'?

```
SELECT fehler.*, `maschine.Maschinen-Typ`, maschine.Auftragsnummer, maschine.Kunde, maschine.Liefertermin_Soll 
FROM fehler 
JOIN maschine 
ON ltrim(rtrim(`maschine.Maschinen-Nr`)) = ltrim(rtrim(`fehler.Maschinen_Nr`))
```

Last line compared a string to a number. This should be doing it.
Also, use the backtick to reference the column names.

Comment: oh i think thats what i am doing wrong. i was using the ' to mask it since when i didnt it always showed "unknown table field maschine.Maschinen" so it was missing the -Nr. i guess it dowsnt like the - whats the propper way to do it in that case?

Comment: you can put \`arround the maschine.Maschinen-Nr so it would be \`maschine.Maschinen-Nr\` !!!Those are not the normal quotes!!!

Answer (score 0):

To avoid this problems in future, the convention for DB's is snake case(lowercase_lowercase).

Besides that, posting your DB schema would be really helpfull since i dont guess your data structures.

(For friendly development, is usefull that variables, tables and columns should be written in english)

So with this, what is the error that you get, because if table "maschine" has a column named "Maschinen-Nr" and table "fehler" has a column named "Maschinen_Nr" and the fields match each other, it should be correct

be careful with Maschinen-Nr and Maschinen_Nr. they have - and _ on purpose?

a very blind solution because you dont really tell what is your problem or even your schema is:

```
SELECT table1Alias.*, table2Alias.column_name, table2Alias.column_name
FROM table1 [table1Alias] 
JOIN table2 [table2Alias]
ON ltrim(rtrim(table1Alias.matching_column)) = ltrim(rtrim(table2Alias.matching_column))
```

where matching_columns are respectively PK and FK or if the data matches both columns [] are optional and if not given, will be consider table_name